# `gorm` get id for update

Tags: go, go-gorm

Tell me, I want to get auto id records

To get a new record I use

```
db.Create (& good)
db.Last (& good)
id: = good.Id
```

This works, but how do I get the id of the record if I update?

```
db.Model (& good) .Where ("url =?", url).
Update ("Name", good.Name)

id: = ???
```

thank

Answer (score 0):

my decision

```golang
     db.Model(&good).Where("siteid = ?", siteid).Updates(map[string]interface{}{"Name": good.Name,"UrlImgThumb": good.UrlImgThumb})
     db.Last(&good, "siteid = ?", siteid)
     id := good.Id
```